# No filament extrusion using G-code from Ultimaker Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code, ultimaker-2

I am trying to print some objects using an Ultimaker 2+ Connect that is available at my work.

It has a slicer with a web interface and that works fine, but it has some limitations that I am trying to work around.

So I downloaded Ultimaker Cura and tried to use that instead. Unfortunately the files that it generates don't work.

The printer loads it and starts printing as expected, but no filament is extruded. Do any of you have a hint as to what is going wrong?

- [Working G-code](https://pastebin.com/sw0TdPj4)
- [Non-working G-code (Cura)](https://pastebin.com/9MKqVrX0)

Comment: Is the extruder moving at all in the non-working version? I'm guessing it's an absolute vs relative position mode of the extruder.

Comment: @LarryBud Yes, it appears to move exactly as it should. Just doesn’t extrude any filament. I experimented and replaced the start and end of the non-working file with the start and end of the working one and then it printed correctly, so it must be something in the start up sequence.

Comment: Yes, then it's the absolute vs relative position mode of the extruder. I would suggest making a super simple model, one which draws a straight line for 1mm, slice it in both, and see the difference.  Make sure you have the correct printer selected in Cura so that the startup code is correct.